# magento rewrite model confusion

Tags: php, magento, model, url-rewriting, before-save

I rewrite the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` with  these codes in mu `config.xml` of `shopby module`

```
<sales>
    <rewrite>
        <order_item>Amasty_Shopby_Model_Mostordered</order_item>
    </rewrite>
</sales>
```

and these code is in my `mostordered.php` in the shopby model folder

```
class Amasty_Shopby_Model_Mostordered extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item{
    protected  function _beforeSave()
    {
        die(var_dump($this->getData('order_id')));
        return parent::_beforeSave();
    }
}
```

the code shown in above doesn't work but when i write the die in `_beforeSave` in item.php in the 
`sales/model/order/item.php` it works and it means my rewrite way is wrong in somewhere

```
protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        die('something');
        parent::_beforeSave();
        if (!$this->getOrderId() && $this->getOrder()) {
            $this->setOrderId($this->getOrder()->getId());
        }
        if ($this->getParentItem()) {
            $this->setParentItemId($this->getParentItem()->getId());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

my only goal is to change the _beforesave method of this php folder
where was i mistaking?

**update:**
i found another module that rewrite the same class as i want.so i think because of this my code doesn't work.what is the way to duplicate rewritng?

Comment: When you die, the return never will happen.

Comment: It's not advisable to rewrite chunks of a 3rd-party extension to Magento; when Amasty update that module (security or bugfix for example) you'll have to remember what you've changed and work out how to merge in the new version - you'd be better off creating a new module to extend it.

Comment: when i die it should show me the thing in die but it doesn't show and work correctly as it was in before .(to Markus Zeller)

Comment: If you replace your calls of `die` with Mage::log, do you have anything in var/log/system.log ?

Comment: nicolallias i check it but it doesn't return my log file.(that was writen in mage::log syntax)